# How to form url and send http request with data in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-headers, npm-request

i want to form url with below "Raw Request" then send request to it in nodejs,how can i do this.

```
Raw Request:
-----------

POST /sky?api_key="" HTTP/1.1
Host: https://sky.in
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: close
Content-Length: 82
{"registration_ids":[""], "data":{"message":"Hello World!"}}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [request](https://github.com/request/request) module:

```
var request = require('request')
request.post('https://sky.in/sky', {
  qs: {
    api_key: ''
  },
  json: {
    registration_ids: [],
    data: {message: 'Hello World!'}
  },
}, function (err, res, body) {
  // body contains the parsed JSON response
})
```

Comment: Great! Mark this question as answered then.